# Remove " and \ using Replace

Tags: c#

```
string a = "\"address\": {\r\n  \"label\":"


string b = "{\r\n  \"label\":"


a.replace(""\"address\": ", "")
```

The goal is to remove the data ""\"address\":" and retrieve the same value as string b?

Comment: Good luck. Let us know how you got on...

Comment: any output sample?

Comment: What is the actual output? The syntax must be `a.replace("\"address\": ","")` and it's not self-updated. Try `string c=a.replace("\"address\": ","")`

Comment: If you're working with Json you really should consider using a parser instead of manipulating the string directly.

Comment: Output is "{\r\n  \"label\":"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to parse a **double quote** in a string you must place a slash before the quote: **"\""** Not like it's needed in this example anyway, since it is already embbeded in the string. The solutionn to your question:

```
        string a = "\"address\": {\r\n  \"label\":";
        string b = "{\r\n  \"label\":";
        a = a.Replace("\"address\": ", "");
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, you had 1 quote toomany in the replace

```
a.Replace("\"address\": ", "")
```

Comment: `Replace`, with a capital R.

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.Replace("\\\"address\\\": ", "")`

Comment: Based on the posted code there are no actual backslashes in the string, they are just the delimiters for the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could with benefit use the @ operator in front of the string. By doing so, you do not have to escape the code, thus creating a code which is more readable :-)